# Adding '...' to end of message.content if char limit is over 2045

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm wanting to do something that would prevent the whole message not being sent as in like for the bot to throw an error if it didn't successfully send said message.

Say the message was:

`Hello world, I am Johnty *1000+ more chars here*`

I want it to be able to do like:

`Hello world, I am Johnty *500+ more chars here*...`

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`${message.content}`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so simple, it wasn't until a fellow Plexi Development member showed me how to.

Thanks [Cats Are Awesome#3153](https://dsc.bio/CatsAreAwesome)

#### Code:

```js
const trim = (str, max) => (str.length > max ? `${str.slice(0, max - 3)}...` : str);
```

#### Usage:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const trim = (str, max) => (str.length > max ? `${str.slice(0, max - 3)}...` : str);
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`${trim(message.content, 500)}`);
message.channel.send(embed);
```